# getHtmlContentで取得した内容をHTMLに書き込む

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function getHTML() {
    var pages = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("GoogleサイトのページのURL");
    var contents = pages.getHtmlContent();
}
```

ここまでで、指定したページのコンテンツをHTMLで取得できました。(Logger.logで確認したところ、しっかり取得できていました。)

ここから、プロジェクト内のHTMLに、取得したHTMLを書き込みたいと思っています。
すなわち、Googleサイトのページの内容だけをHTMLとして表示させたいです。

調べてみると

```
var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
return output.evaluate();
```

で書き込めるという解説があったのですが、エラーが出て保存できません。
(※エラーは解消できました)

ここからどうやって変数contentsをindex.htmlに書き込むのかが分かりません。

どなたかやり方を教えてください！

Comment: 提供されている情報だけでは何も分からないので、回答が難しいです。エラーを追記してください。テンプレートの書き方が間違っている可能性があるので、テンプレート`index.html` も追記してください。

Comment: すみません、エラーは解消できました。functionの中に入れ忘れていたからでしょうか、「戻り値が無効です」というエラーが出ていました。

index.htmlについてですが、そもそもHTMLの書き方というか、どういう記述をすれば、
`var pages = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("GoogleサイトのページのURL");
 var contents = pages.getHtmlContent();`
で取得した内容を
`var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
return output.evaluate();`
でindex.htmlに書き込めるのか、という部分がわかりません。
変数contentsをbody内に書き込む、ということです。

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございました。